# Communication between specific web page and chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to create a communication channel between specific webpage (per example : www.website.dev) and a chrome extension I created.

By using postMessage it's work from webpage to extension but I can't do that from extension to webpage.

I tried Google example but it uses background page

Thanks for your help

EDIT : sorry I don't understand the difference between content_script and background.js
In my manifest I have content script = test.js 
What's about "background" ?

Answer (score 3):

Following the documentation you can pass messages to your extension if you know the extension id:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

manifest.json

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

website:

```
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.url == blocklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
      openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
  });
```

Comment: How can the website _receive_ messages from the extension?

Answer (score 0):

You will find all the details in the documentation https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

You would have one piece use sendMessage function while the other piece is listening for the event, which could be either a webpage or content script.

either the webpage's content script should initiate the communication (so you would get the tab id) or you can have the background query for tabs with specific url and then use sendMessage. Notice two separate functions `chrome.extension.sendMessage` and `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` used here.

the following code works for me:

**content_script.js:**

`chrome.extension.sendMessage({"msg":"hello"});`

**background.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.msg == "hello"){
    senderTab = sender.tab.id;
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(senderTab, {"msg": "ehlo"});
  };
})
```

Comment: I believe the user is asking how to communicate between the page and the content script, not between the content script and the background script.